# I have an 08 Ford Escape, limited 4x4

Tags: engine, ford, escape

Sat. Had tune up. Sun. Check engine light cam on. Shop said clamp came off. Monday going 40 mph the rpms went to 3.5. Normally at 50 mph the rpms at 1.5.  I would like to know what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does your Escape have a standard or automatic transmission? What was the code for the engine light?

Comment: Auto. Have to apologize. I'm not a mechanic. Thought I could get answers or advice.